# "Random" effects from "fixed" variables (in logistic regression)?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I've been getting a bit lost in translation when it comes to the term "random" in "random effects" and "random sampling". I found a lot of useful posts on how to define a fixed or random effect, but I can't seem to bridge the gap between these definitions and how I should analyze my data.

I'm attempting to fit a logistic regression model to my observations that come from fixed sites/locations of interest over time (there are non-dependence issues given the repeated measures nature of the data). I've heard that modelling the site/location variable as a "random effect" fixes this non-independence problem, but I don't understand how to interpret this advice back to the real world situation. As in, where is the random effect coming from in a fixed variable?

Understandably, these locations are underwater so conditions can vary a little with time, but I thought the definition of a "fixed" effect was that:

1. All values of location of interest are present for all observations and not randomly selected
2. I'm only making inferences about the site/location values I've collected from

For example, the presence/absence of sharks can be modeled with the variables "location", "changes in temperature" and "time" (1 value (present or absent) with 1 temperature reading and 1 time stamp, per site, for many sites, twice per year). As I understand it, logistic regression requires independent observations and since I have fixed/repeated observations over time, I don't understand how making this variable a random effect will help...

Unfortunately I have to work with the data I'm given and can't resample. I'm open to different ideas as well, thank you!

Comment: This question reads like the continuation of a previous question (example: "understandably, these locations are underwater"). I suggest that you start by summarizing the data, your research question and your analysis so far.

Comment: They are related, yes. Essentially the question is: Do I need to include a fixed variable as a random effect to properly model binomial data from a repeated measures sampling design. But, I'll think about it more in the mean time.

Comment: I think I got it, or close enough hopefully. It's not the values of "site", but the processes AT the site that we are trying to account for in our model that are, perhaps, characteristic of each "site". The random effect comes from what happens at the site, not the effect of randomly picking a number to represent site "1" or "12".